# How to change the default size of the view on ViewerJS

Tags: javascript, html

I use [ViewerJS](http://viewerjs.org/) to show a PDF file on a html page.

In the first viewer in [this page](http://viewerjs.org/), you first see a document in the size `Automatic`.

I would like to set "`Full Width`" as default, not "`Automatic`",

thus, I edited index.html the ViewerJS folder as below. (I moved `selected` for the option from `value="auto"` to `value="page-width"`.)

```
<select id="scaleSelect" title="Zoom" oncontextmenu="return false;">
<option id="pageAutoOption" value="auto">Automatic</option>
<option id="pageActualOption" value="page-actual">Actual Size</option>
<option id="pageWidthOption" value="page-width" selected>Full Width</option>
<option id="customScaleOption" value="custom"> </option>
<option value="0.5">50%</option>
<option value="0.75">75%</option>
<option value="1">100%</option>
<option value="1.25">125%</option>
<option value="1.5">150%</option>
<option value="2">200%</option>
</select>
```

However, when I open the page which uses ViewerJS, the default is still `Automatic` not `Full Width`.

The folder contains java script files. Should I edit java script files?
How can I change the default?

Answer (score 4):

As stated [here](https://github.com/kogmbh/ViewerJS/issues/58), from version 0.5.5 you can set the initial scale to Full Width by specifying *?zoom=page-width* in the url that links to the document. E.g.:

```
src="/ViewerJS/?zoom=page-width#yourfile.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

in viewer.js change values in defaultPreferences function.

```
 defaultPreferences = Promise.resolve({
                    "showPreviousViewOnLoad": true,
                    "defaultZoomValue": "page-height",
                    "sidebarViewOnLoad": 0,
                    "enableHandToolOnLoad": false,
                    "enableWebGL": false,
                    "pdfBugEnabled": false,
                    "disableRange": false,
                    "disableStream": false,
                    "disableAutoFetch": false,
                    "disableFontFace": false,
                    "disableTextLayer": true,
                    "useOnlyCssZoom": false,
                    "externalLinkTarget": 0,
                    "enhanceTextSelection": false,
                    "renderer": "canvas",
                    "renderInteractiveForms": false,
                    "disablePageLabels": false
                });
```